# Share Sesssion Or Cookies Data between Domain and Sub Domain

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

I have a situation in my main domain. If I already login in subdomain then I have to show a pop-up message in my main domain otherwise I have to hidden that pop up. My main domain is developed on wordpress and sub-domain is developed on laravel. I have to get a response or message from my sub-domain that I am already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality, you can use AJAX to send a request from your main domain (WordPress) to your subdomain (Laravel) to check if the user is logged in. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Create an API endpoint in your Laravel subdomain that checks if the user is logged in. For example, you could create a route in Laravel like /api/check-login that returns a JSON response indicating the login status.
2. In your WordPress theme or plugin, add JavaScript code to make an AJAX request to the Laravel API endpoint. You can use the jQuery.ajax() method or any other library of your choice. Make sure to include the CSRF token if your Laravel application uses CSRF protection.

Example using jQuery:

```
// Assuming you have included jQuery library in your WordPress site

// Make an AJAX request to the Laravel API endpoint
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://subdomain.example.com/api/check-login',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    // Handle the response from the subdomain
    if (response.logged_in) {
      // User is logged in, show the pop-up
      // Add your code to show the pop-up here
    } else {
      // User is not logged in, hide the pop-up
      // Add your code to hide the pop-up here
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
    console.error('AJAX error:', error);
  }
});
```

3. Customize the API endpoint in your Laravel subdomain (/api/check-login) to check the user's login status. You can use Laravel's built-in authentication mechanisms or your custom logic to determine if the user is logged in. Return a JSON response indicating the login status.

Example in Laravel:

```
// In your Laravel routes file (routes/api.php or routes/web.php)
Route::get('/check-login', function () {
  $isLoggedIn = Auth::check(); // Check if the user is logged in using Laravel's authentication
   
  return response()->json(['logged_in' => $isLoggedIn]);
});
```

---

By following these steps, you can send an AJAX request from your WordPress main domain to the Laravel subdomain to check if the user is logged in, and then show or hide the pop-up based on the response received.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score -3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Make an AJAX request to the subdomain
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://subdomain.example.com/check-login', // Replace with your subdomain URL
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true // Send cookies along with the request
    },
    success: function(response) {
      // Handle the response from the subdomain
      if (response.isLoggedIn) {
        // User is logged in, show the pop-up message
        // Your code to show the pop-up message goes here
      } else {
        // User is not logged in, hide the pop-up message
        // Your code to hide the pop-up message goes here
      }
    }
  });
});
write this js into new check-login.js file and 
write bellow code into web.php file

// routes/web.php (in your Laravel subdomain)
Route::get('/check-login', function() {
  if (Auth::check()) {
    // User is logged in, return the appropriate response
    return response()->json(['isLoggedIn' => true]);
  } else {
    // User is not logged in, return the appropriate response
    return response()->json(['isLoggedIn' => false]);
  }
});
```